# Redirecting certain URL to another in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

Ok, quite alot here. I've recently changed domain names and I need to redirect quite a few things. Firstly..

All pages of

http://helloarchie.blue (old domain)

need to redirect to

http://helloarchie.co (new domain).

So far only the homepage redirects set up through the cPanel.

I also need to redirect all images with this URL:

http://kaye.at/img/

to

http://helloarchie.co/img/

Here's my htaccess currently.

```
Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kaye\.at$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png|gif|pdf|jpg|doc)$ http://helloarchie.co/$1 [NC,L,R]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.helloarchie\.co [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://helloarchie.co/$1 [L,R=301]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kaye\.at$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png|gif|pdf|jpg|doc)$ http://helloarchie.co/$1 [NC,L,R]   only redirect png, git, pdf, jpg, doc file.   Is that what you want ?   What is the issue ?

Comment: I've clarified my query a bit better (hopefully).

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.helloarchie\.co [NC]   ==> should be RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.helloarchie\.blue [NC]

Comment: Works for homepage but not individual pages, ie. http://helloarchie.blue/press

Comment: And if you remove the 3 "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ..."  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your rules:

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?helloarchie\.blue$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://helloarchie.co%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kaye\.at$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png|gif|pdf|jpe?g|doc)$ http://helloarchie.co/$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @KayeHuett: Did this help you?